# Cómo imprimir desde un Form Feed hasta una linea antes del siguiente FF si se cumple alguna condición con Python

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente archivo de texto donde "\f" es mi Form Feed y comienza una nueva página

```
 \f    16/09/1899     nro 123

texto largo texto largo texto largo 

en esta linea entre las columnas **[96:102]** tengo un nro "**1889944**"

que es la condición que tiene que cumplir para poder imprimir el texto

 \f         11/12/2004     nro 1256

texto largo texto largo texto largo 
y no siempre la misma cantidad de filas en los archivos

en esta linea entre las columnas **[96:102]** tengo un nro "**2889990**"

que es la condición que tiene que tener para poder imprimir el texto

 \f         11/12/2004     nro 1256 y asi unas 200.000 lineas mas
```

lo que necesito es poder imprimir el texto donde se encuentra mi condición hasta una linea antes del ff siguiente donde termina dicho texto:

```
\f     16/09/1899     nro 123
texto largo texto largo texto largo 
en esta linea entre las columnas [96:102] tengo un nro "1889944"
que es la condición que tiene que cumplir para poder imprimir el texto
```

mi codigo hasta ahora es el siguiente, pero no me funciona siempre porque no tengo siempre la misma cantidad de filas entre los FF, pero si siempre esta el FF de inicio de cada parte del archivo:

```
import collections
import sys
import itertools
with open("archivo.txt") as f:
    before = collections.deque(maxlen=9)
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if '1889944' == line[96:102]:
            sys.stdout.writelines(before)
            sys.stdout.write(line)
            sys.stdout.writelines(itertools.islice(f, 81))
            break
        before.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es hacer un bucle que vaya recopilando en una lista todas las líneas que ha leido hasta ese momento. Cuando lea una línea que comienza por `\f` sabremos que hemos completado una "página" y que tenemos todas las líneas de esa página en la lista. Entonces procesamos esa lista para ver si cumple la condición de contener el número en cuestión y de ser así la imprimimos.

Para verificar si tiene el número resulta más cómodo tener una función, así como otra para imprimir la página.

El siguiente código implementa estas ideas. No necesitas `itertools` ni `collections`:

```
def verificar(pagina, numero):
  # Recorremos las lineas acumuladas
  for linea in pagina:
    # buscando si alguna tiene el numero. En este caso me vale
    # que aparezca en cualquier posicion de la linea, pero puedes
    # cambiar la condicion por if numero == linea[96:102]
    if numero in linea:
      return True
  return False

def volcar(pagina):
  # Juntamos todas las lineas en una sola cadena que imprimimos
  print("\n".join(pagina))


pagina = []   # Lista donde acumularemos lineas hasta el proximo \f
with open("archivo.txt") as fichero:
  for linea in fichero:
    if linea.startswith("\f"):
        # Tenemos entonces una pagina completa. La procesamos
        if verificar(pagina, "1889944"):
            volcar(pagina)
        # y comenzamos una pagina nueva
        pagina = []
    # Vamos acumulando lineas en la lista
    pagina.append(linea)
```

Con el fichero que suministras la salida es:

```
    16/09/1899     nro 123
texto largo texto largo texto largo 
en esta linea entre las columnas **[96:102]** tengo un nro "**1889944**"
que es la condición que tiene que cumplir para poder imprimir el texto
```

Comment: Gracias funciona tu codigo solo le añadi **[96:102]** en `if numero in linea[96:102]:` sino me traia todo lo que tenga el numero buscado y yo solo necesitaba los que esten entre esas columnas, una ultima consulta, como puedo guardar este resultado en otro archivo txt?